# Make a record entry from one table reference several records from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to mySQL and have come across a (probably very simple) problem that has me stumped.
I have 2 tables - a User table and an Activity table. A User may engage in several activities, which are stored as unique entries in the Activity table. I've created a new column in the User table, and I now want a record in that column to hold 1 or more entries that correspond to an 'activityID' in the Activity table.
I thought 'set' might be the appropriate data type, but I'm not so sure... I also want this column to act as a foreign key, so any entries must match 'activityID'.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a third table to hold that relationship.

That table could be named **UserActivities** and have at least two columns:
*userID
activityID*

What's the data type of these columns? Use the same as the corresponding id fields in User and Activity

Pedro

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Both are of data type 'int', although I could actually get away with changing them to 'mediumint', as I won't be needing 2 billion entries...